# Following implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user model and a store model. I would like to setup the model associations in order for a user to be able follow a store. Which means that the user will be the follower and the store will be the followed.

I created a follow model for this purpose and added associations to the other models as well:

```
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :follows do |t|
      t.integer :store_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :uid

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
end
```

It's working, but I'm pretty sure that this is not the correct setup for this. I also found this [tutorial](https://dev.to/knheidorn/rails-crash-course-building-follower-following-relationship-4kjl) but I cant figure out how to use it in my case. Any ideas on how to setup the model associations correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the user be able to follow more than one store or just one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @borjagvo. Yes that is correct, the user will be able to follow more than one store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got it.

What you're missing is letting a User see the Stores they follow, and vice versa. Do that with [`has_many :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
  has_many :stores, through: :follows
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows
  has_many :users, through: :follows
end
```

Now `user.stores` will fetch the Stores that User follows, and `store.users` will fetch which Users follow that Store. It will handle the joins for you and cache the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Schwern. I kind of figured that something was missing. I'll give it a try and I'll let you know! :))))))

Comment: Hey @Schwern, I tested it and it works just fine! I have one more question though, is there a way I can also get the individual follow of the current user... something like this `current_user.store`?

Comment: @Theopap No, because the user is following many stores. There is no single store the user is following.